# chrome.notifications message not showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

According to the [Chrome extension documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-NotificationOptions), `message` in `NotificationOptions` defines the main notification content to be shown on the notification created. However, take a look at this snippet:

```
chrome.notifications.create("some id", {
    type: "list",
    title: "Title",
    message: "Message",
    iconUrl: "icon.png",
    items: [{
        title: "Title",
        message: "Message"
    }]
}, function () {});
```

This will create such a notification:

> [image]

Notice that the main message is missing. There's a way, however, to show text under the title by using `contextMessage`, but it would make the text gray.

I suspect this is a bug, since the notification API requires the `message` property to be provided, and it doesn't make sense to require a property without using it.

Am I doing something wrong here, or it's just a bug? Or maybe it is intended?

Comment: I think what happens is `items` property overriding `message` property. You can't have both.

Comment: This does look like a bug. I'd recommend asking at the google group (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions)

Comment: It does look like a bug: `message` property is still required but not used, as you mentioned.

Comment: @Xan - Not only that; In the official docs, under the `type:list` example, it says `message: "Primary message to display",` which to me implies that the message should be displayed but it currently isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for this report!  I created https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=384025 to track fixing this inconsistency.

Comment: Great to see another Chrome dev on SO. I'll be awarding you a bounty in a couple of days (impossible to do so sooner than 3 days after the question is asked) so you can use Stack Overflow properly. Unless someone beats me to it.